# Reference a filename in form validation for an image

Tags: forms, files

I am new to Drupal and am making a module to alter a content type. I have a content type that allows a user to submit an email and an image and I want to change the filename of the image to the email before it submits to the database. I figured I can do this in the form validation but I am having trouble finding the right code to access the filename value using $form_state. I am using the form alter hook and adding to the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get value using Form API

```
$upload = $form_state->getValue('file');
$file = File::load($upload[0]);
$file->setPermanent();
$file->setFilename(‘test’);
$file->save();
```